# How to disable CONTROL+PAGE_UP of a JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, jtabbedpane

How to disable the default behavior of CONTROL+PAGE_UP and CONTROL+PAGE_DOWN of a `JTabbedPane`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code disables the usual behavior

```
JTabbedPane jTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
KeyStroke ctrlTab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl PAGE_DOWN");
KeyStroke ctrlShiftTab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl PAGE_UP");
InputMap inputMap = jTabbedPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
inputMap.put(ctrlTab, "none");
inputMap.put(ctrlShiftTab, "none");
```

Here is an example for [Switching tab using Ctrl + Tab](http://www.davidc.net/programming/java/how-make-ctrl-tab-switch-tabs-jtabbedpane)

Answer (score 3):

- KeyBindings are used for internall commands (for Swing JComponents)
- see list of [KeyBindings by @camickr](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/)

[image]

- get `ctrl PAGE_DOWN` / `ctrl PAGE_UP` (implemented KeyBindings in API for JTabbedPane)  and to set to null