# Java Swing get input

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

How can I change this code to accept any key (not only F5) and print the key?

```
component.getRootPane().getInputMap(JRootPane.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F5, 0), "F5 Pressed");
component.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("F5 Pressed", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Code here
    }
});
```

Comment: You may be looking for a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).

Comment: you can't - keybindings are meant for _specific_ keyStrokes. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Seems like you wanted to add every key on the keyboard to be mapped with this component. At the same time, you wanted, it to be done with a minimum of code. I hope I am write in describing your situation. Please do replace __cahnhe__ to ___change___, seems like you meant to write the latter, but typed the former :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `KeyboardFocusManager` to register a `KeyEventDispatcher`:

```
KeboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {       
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke) {
        if (yourComponent.hasFocus && ke.getID == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
            // Your code here
            // Use ke.getKeyChar() to detect which key was pressed.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> how can I ("cahnhe") this code to accept any key (not only F5) and print
>   the key?

- sorry this question doesn't make me some sence, in this form
- basic is [described in tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#howto),
- `component.getRootPane()` could be valid only for [`JFrame`, `JDialog`, `JWindow`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15165333/714968), practically only `JFrame` has accesible `RootPane`
- otherwise to add [`Input/ActionMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7940227/714968) to the desired [`JComponent` directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16558988/714968)